What am I missing ? BST hidden case failure
Some hidden test cases fail to output correctly. I've tested for all edge cases I can think of; what am I missing?
Edge Cases Tested:

Nonexistent Key Deletion: Assumes input is valid per the problem description.
Empty Tree Operations: Handled by checks at the root.
Successor of the Largest Key: Assumes input guarantees the key has a successor.
Deleting the Root: Properly adjusts the root pointer for all cases.
Tree with Only One Node: Both delete and minKey behave as expected.
methods containing the error in question:

public void delete(int k) {
        Node nodeToDelete = getDescendant(root, k);

        // Case 1: Node has no children (leaf node)
        if (nodeToDelete.left == null && nodeToDelete.right == null) {
            if (nodeToDelete == root) {
                root = null;
            } else if (nodeToDelete.parent.left == nodeToDelete) {
                nodeToDelete.parent.left = null;
            } else {
                nodeToDelete.parent.right = null;
            }
        }
        // Case 2: Node has one child
        else if (nodeToDelete.left == null || nodeToDelete.right == null) {
            Node child = (nodeToDelete.left != null) ? nodeToDelete.left : nodeToDelete.right;

            if (nodeToDelete == root) {
                root = child;
            } else if (nodeToDelete.parent.left == nodeToDelete) {
                nodeToDelete.parent.left = child;
            } else {
                nodeToDelete.parent.right = child;
            }
            child.parent = nodeToDelete.parent;
        }
        // Case 3: Node has two children
        else {
            Node successor = minDescendant(nodeToDelete.right);
            int successorKey = successor.key;
            delete(successorKey); // Remove the successor
            nodeToDelete.key = successorKey; // Replace node's key with successor's key
        }
    }

    private Node minDescendant(Node n) {
        Node current = n;
        while (current.left != null) {
            current = current.left;
        }
        return current;
    }

    public int successorKey(int k) {
        Node node = getDescendant(root, k);

        // Case 1: Node has a right subtree
        if (node.right != null) {
            return minDescendant(node.right).key;
        }

        // Case 2: No right subtree; move up to find the successor
        Node ancestor = node.parent;
        while (ancestor != null && node == ancestor.right) {
            node = ancestor;
            ancestor = ancestor.parent;
        }
        return ancestor.key;
    }

    public int minKey() {
        return minDescendant(root).key;
    }


    /* Part (b) methods */

    public int medianKey() {
        List<Integer> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        inOrderTraversal(root, sortedKeys);

        // Median key is the middle of the sorted keys
        int n = sortedKeys.size();
        return sortedKeys.get((n - 1) / 2);
    }

    private void inOrderTraversal(Node node, List<Integer> keys) {
        if (node == null) return;
        inOrderTraversal(node.left, keys);
        keys.add(node.key);
        inOrderTraversal(node.right, keys);
    }


    /* Part (c) methods */

    public int nodesInLevel(int h) {
        return countNodesAtLevel(root, h, 0);
    }

    private int countNodesAtLevel(Node node, int targetLevel, int currentLevel) {
        if (node == null) return 0;
        if (currentLevel == targetLevel) return 1;

        int leftCount = countNodesAtLevel(node.left, targetLevel, currentLevel + 1);
        int rightCount = countNodesAtLevel(node.right, targetLevel, currentLevel + 1);

        return leftCount + rightCount;
    }


If this problem comes from a web page, such as a programming challenge / practice site, it would be polite and possibly helpful to include a link to that page.  It might help to take a close look at the conditions and constraints.

You forgot to tell us what the task is, which function you are asking about, what it is supposed to do, and what it does instead.
